# How to dynamically change the script in index.html -- Angular

Tags: angular

I have google analytics code in index.html, all I want to do is setting the trackingID from other component.

```
<script>
.....
.....
.....
ga('create', 'UA-83987994-2', 'auto');
// change to ga('create', trackingID, 'auto')
</script>
```

Tracking ID is 'UA-83987994-2', I want to set it dynamically from other component,

eg. general-settings.component.html

```
<md-input-container class="full-width" id="gatracking">
  <input name="code" mdInput placeholder="Enter ID. Eg: GTM-XXXXXXX" required>
</md-input-container>
```

Is there any possible solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: do you use webpack?

Comment: no, I didnt use webpack